# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach') fetch api

Tags: javascript, html, fetch-api

I tried to fetch API from https://js.cexplorer.io/api-static/basic/global.json

```
<script>
                  fetch("https://js.cexplorer.io/api-static/basic/global.json")
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(d => {
  let data1 = "";
  
  d.records.forEach(values => {
    data1 += `<div class="card">
        
        <p class="name">${v.data.supply.genesis}</p>
        <p class="occupation">${v.data.supply.max}</p>
      </div>`;
  });

  document.querySelector(".test").innerHTML = data1;
})
.catch(e => console.log(e));

</script>
```

I have a div on homepage

```
<div class='test'></div>
```

i got this error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')  but i don't understand why this error.

Comment: Because there is no `records` property in the response... So `d.records` is `undefined`, so `d.records.forEach` is essentially `undefined.forEach` and you cannot read properties of `undefined` (`forEach` in this case)

Comment: okay, if i put d.data.ForEach instaed records (my error) i get 
TypeError: d.data.forEach is not a function and not work

Comment: High Order Functions only works for Arrays not object. Since URL returns nested objects not array.

Comment: `d.data` is not an array, it's an object... You need to look at the data you are trying to read first so you know how to read it! Why do you even try to do any iterating here at all? I can't see any arrays in the response whatsoever... It's just `d.data.supply.genesis` etc.

Answer (score 1):

The data from your json file does not contain a **records** array to iterate with forEach().

```
.then(d => {
  let data1 = "";      
  
    data1 += `<div class="card">            
        <p class="name">${d.data.supply.genesis}</p>
        <p class="occupation">${d.data.supply.max}</p>
      </div>`;
....
```

Comment: work! thanks man now can i display the values on div.